# Ant Design Table: can I have pagination shown at both top and bottom?

Tags: antd

I'm using Ant.design Table for pagination. I am wondering if it's possible to add the pagination item both top and bottom since the table is quite large and I would need to scroll down a lot otherwise?

Comment: have you read the documentation?
this is exactly what you need https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-pagination

Comment: thanks I did not see that somehow. if you want to post it as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible
Link to example in documentation
https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-pagination